# Views: greater than a date expose filter

Tags: views

How can I only show the nodes that are greater or equal to the selected date from expose filter on views?

I'd like to have a dropdown/expose filter which allows me to select the nodes that their post dates are greater or equal to (past week, past month, past six month)

Answer (score 1):

In Views, add a filter of *Node: Post date*.  You should see something like the image below (without example values changed):

[image]

Click *Expose* to have the filter exposed to your users, choose the operator *Is greater than or equal to* and choose how you want to filter the results (by inserting a date to be greater than or equal to or entering a value of "-6 months", etc).  This won't present a dropdown, but it will certainly add the filter you need for your view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, but how can I have more than one item as a dropdown menu instead of a textfield so I can limit the selection?