# How to customize exposed filter for date field?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that shows a table of members. I would like to have an option to filter by "new members", let's say members that joined in the last month.

If I expose the field I get an input box with "-1 month" which isn't ideal. 
It would be better to have a "select box" with "Any" and "New Members" options. A previous [DA question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12231/views-greater-than-a-date-expose-filter) didn't show an answer for this option.

Alternatively, links for "All Members" and "New Members" would work for me too. If I expose the field I can make the link work. But then I have to somehow hide the text field.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own form controls to send his values to exposed filters. For example, create your own select list inside a *exposed filters* template (`views-exposed-form.tpl.php`). This select list can have your desired options with respective values, according is needed in the exposed filter, for example:

```
<select id="edit-date" class="form-select" name="date">
<option value="-1 day">New members</option>
<option value="-7 day">Members within 1 week</option>
<option value="-30 day">Members within 1 month</option>
<option value="">All members</option>
</select>
```

Also, if you need a more complex behavior, you can alter view's queries with `query_alter` hook. [This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11110/making-a-field-sortable-in-views/11263#11263) is an example of how to use `query_alter` with a custom select list.

I hope information be useful.

Answer (score 0):

for reference, I ended up hiding the exposed filter element with css and using a link in a block to get the filtered view.
I used firebug to find the div of the exposed filter and then used the [css_injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) module to inject this css for the view page:

```
.views-widget-filter-created {
  display:none;
}
```

Another option would be to clone your view, add the filter (without exposing it) and then linking to it.